# How can I log validation error in asp .net

Tags: asp.net, validation, logging

I need to log validation error in asp .net so that I can know which fields users often input wrong data.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a custom validator to the page that runs on the server and logs the pages validation errors to a specific data source.

Obviously this wouldn't be great for the long term but would allow you to temporarily monitor any fields that are being filled in incorrectly.

In the validator you could if you already have validators on the page, check which ones are incorrect or if you currently don't have any validators write some custom code to validate the fields.

Comment: I agree with Pasha and like I said this would ideally be for a short period of time and smaller projects

Answer (score 1):

Apart from SCB's answer you should really look at logging mechanisisms out there. Many people for example use Log4Net (Free), EnterpriseLibraries (Microsoft). There are various tools out there. I have used both of the above. But in your scenario the question would be:

- On how many pages do you want to log them and how many validators there is per page.

If your scenario is a small one I would not bother doing to much work around it but if it has to potential to grow past the current small scope to be mid to large scale I would recommend you look at the above suggestions. If you are worried about costs try Log4Net.